# How to load/draw an image using NGraphics?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ngraphics, ncontrol

In my Xamarin Forms app, I have an image under `androidProject/Resources/drawable/myImage.png`.  To load these from Xamarin, you can simply do

```
Image myImage = new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromFile("myImage.png") };
```

However, there is no way to draw an `Image` using NGraphics.  Instead, NGraphics `DrawImage(IImage)` requires an `IImage`.  As far as I can tell, there's no way to turn a `Xamarin.Forms.Image` into an `NGraphics.IImage`.  In fact, the *only* way I could find to load `IImage` is

```
IImage myImage = Platform.LoadImage("myImage.png");
```

However, this doesn't work because under the hood this uses `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`, which requires the absolute file path.  And I couldn't find any way to get the absolute file path of a resource (if it even exists?)

So, **how do I actually load and display an image using NGraphics?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works in Maui.  The image being loaded needs to be in the `Resources` for the project that's loading the image (not the main cross-platform Resources folder), and needs to have build action `Embedded Resource`.  In this example, I have the image under `Ringotan.KanjiControl/Resources/next_arrow.png`

```
if (_arrowImage == null)
{
    Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    using Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Ringotan.KanjiControl.Resources.next_arrow.png");
    _arrowImage = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
}
canvas.DrawImage(_arrowImage, (float)rect.Left, (float)rect.Top, (float)rect.Width, (float)rect.Height);
```

Answer (score 1):

NGraphics does not provide any helpers to load images from your Platforms Resource files.

You could do something as follows. However, it will add some overhead converting back and forth between bitmap -> stream -> bitmap.

Android:

```cs
Stream GetDrawableStream(Context context, int resourceId)
{
    var drawable = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(context.Resources, resourceId, context.Theme);
    if (drawable is BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 80, stream);
        bitmap.Recycle();
        return stream;
    }

    return null;
}
```

iOS:

```cs
Stream GetImageStream(string fileName)
{
    using (var image = UIImage.FromFile(fileName))
    using (var imageData = image.AsPNG())
    {
        var byteArray = new byte[imageData.Length];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));

        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        return stream;
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, you could go directly from `Bitmap` to `BitmapImage` on Android instead like:

```cs
BitmapImage GetBitmapFromDrawable(Context context, int resourceId)
{
    var drawable = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(context.Resources, resourceId, context.Theme);
    if (drawable is BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable)
    {
        var bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;
        return new BitmapImage(bitmap);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And on iOS:

```cs
CGImageImage GetImageStream(string fileName)
{
    var iOSimage = UIImage.FromFile(fileName);
    var cgImage = new CGImageImage(iOSImage.CGImage, iOSImage.Scale);
    return cgImage;
}
```

`BitmapImage` and `CGImageImage` implement `IImage` in NGraphics.